# Oracle CPU vulnerabilities and Database Proactive Bundle Patch

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, patching

I've applied the latest Oracle 12c Database Proactive Bundle Patch (DBBP).

My security team runs scans and April 2015 CPU (amongst other CPUs) continues to show up as vulnerabilities.

I need to prove that DBBP is a cumulative patch and all those old vulnerabilities are fixed.

`sys.registry$history` doesn't help

```
select ACTION,NAMESPACE,COMMENTS from registry$history;
ACTION                    NAMESPACE    VERSION     COMMENTS
------------------------- ------------ ------------------------
UPGRADE                   SERVER        12.2.0.1.0 Upgraded from 12.1.0.2.0
```

`opatch lsinventory -bugs_fixed`   or   `opatch lsinventory -details` 
    isn't giving me what I want.

How can I find out what vulnerabilities are in April 2015 CPU and prove that DBBP has mitigated them???

Comment: Actually there are times that you can not, I have applied latest patches available and have given them (security team) the logs that show that the patch was installed and was successful. Might be something with DPBP or the security suit being ran. BTW I am lucky enough to only deal with 1 oracle system now and that is the only one being flagged. If your software vendor is using Symantec for the patches, that can be an issue as well, but as it sounds, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word you're looking for is "cumulative".

Note 1962125.1 (Oracle Database - Overview of Database Patch Delivery Methods), includes this text about Bundle Patches:

```
Bundle Patch (BP)
- a cumulative collection of fixes to address bugs in a given feature, product, or configuration
     For example: Windows Database Bundle Patch, Database Patch for Exadata, Database Proactive Bundle Patch
- a superset of PSU
```

So that's all you should need to provide!  BPs include all patches previously included in earlier BPs/PSUs.